# foolproof unpacking of .WARC archives

Tags: python, backup, web, internet, data-extraction

I am looking into options for extracting WARC archive files but the landscape seems very grim

None of the following work:

https://github.com/internetarchive/warctools - apparently does not have capability to extract an entire WARC file

https://github.com/webrecorder/warcio - apparently does not have capability to extract an entire WARC file

https://github.com/internetarchive/warc - doesn't even run

https://github.com/recrm/ArchiveTools - extracts some data but if an error is encountered, aborts extraction with no option to skip/continue

https://github.com/chfoo/warcat - extracts some data but if an error is encountered, aborts extraction with no option to skip/continue

https://theunarchiver.com/command-line - promising, extracts the entire archive, BUT unfortunately HTML files are corrupted

I'm also not interested in "player" software that aims to view the contents of a WARC archive without extracting it.

So all of these are off the table:

github.com/ikreymer/webarchiveplayer

github.com/webrecorder/webrecorder-player

github.com/webrecorder/replayweb.page

replayweb.page

github.com/webrecorder/pywb/

Looking at even more off-the-wall solutions, I found a plugin for 7-zip with extremely primitive WARC capabilities but it was ultimately useless because it didn't preserve directory structure.

I've looked at https://wiki.archiveteam.org/index.php/The_WARC_Ecosystem but I feel I've looked at just about everything and found nothing suitable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm looking for software that will reliably unpack the contents of a .WARC archive file